# Apache using incorrect default virtual host

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

system: ubuntu 14.04 as a VPS, apache 2.4.7

I have several virtual hosts set up, listening to :80 and :443 ports.

If I `apache2ctl -S` it shows incorrect virtual host as default on port 80. And indeed, if I browse to http://default.com, I get the content from another virtual host: the one Apache points as the default, but shouldn't be (customer.com). What is wrong in my setup?

My enabled-sites are :

default.com
customer.com

**apache2ctl -S**

```
    VirtualHost configuration:
    *:80  is a NameVirtualHost
             default server customer.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/customer.com.conf:1)
             port 80 namevhost customer.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/customer.com.conf:1)
             port 80 namevhost www.customer.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/customer.com.conf:19)
             port 80 namevhost www.default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.com.conf:36)
             port 80 namevhost tools.default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.com.conf:41)
             port 80 namevhost phpmyadmin.default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.com.conf:57)

    *:443  is a NameVirtualHost
             default server default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/customer.com.conf:26)
             port 443 namevhost default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/customer.com.conf:26)
             port 443 namevhost default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.com.conf:1)
             port 443 namevhost www.default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.com.conf:31)
             port 443 namevhost default.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:26)
```

**default.com Vhost**

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName default.com

    DocumentRoot /data/www/default.com/public
    <Directory /data/www/default.com/public>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # SSL stuff ...

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/data/www/default.com/public/$1

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.default.com
     RedirectMatch (.*) https://default.com$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.default.com
     RedirectMatch (.*) https://default.com$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tools.default.com

    DocumentRoot /data/www/default.com/subdomains/tools/public

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/data/www/default.com/subdomains/tools/public/$1

    <Directory /data/www/default.com/subdomains/tools/public>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LogLevel error
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.default.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Customer.com vhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customer.com

    DocumentRoot /data/www/customer.com/public
    <Directory /data/www/customer.com/public>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/data/www/customer.com/public/$1

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.customer.com
     RedirectMatch (.*) http://customer.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an entry for the non-www default.com

This should be added to the default.com config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName default.com
     RedirectMatch (.*) https://default.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thank you, that corrected the issue. Still, `apache2ctl -S` shows incorrect default. Does it matter?

Comment: Well, if everything works as it should I wouldn't put too much into what `apache2ctl` says :-)

Comment: Yeah, makes me nervous though. I'm setting up my first VPS for hosting professional projects, I hope my setup is futureproof...

Comment: Update: I managed to fix that by controlling the loading order of all the vhost conf files. I simply renamed my default file from `domain.com.conf` to `000-domain.com.conf`. reloaded Apache. apache2ctl -S now shows the correct default website for each port. Easy peasy.