# One domain on Apache goes to default page without www

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, freebsd

I'm using Apache/2.4.16 on FreeBSD 10.2.  I have two instances of Apache running, each serving several domain names.  The server has two network interfaces, one for the public Internet, one only accessible through my internal LAN.  All of the virtual host configuration files are nearly identical except for the domain names and directories.  All of the sites work as expected, except for one:  If I try to go to adultemployment.net, I get the server's default page, but if I specify any of the machine names configured in the DNS (www, ftp, mail, etc.) I get the site's page as expected, e.g., www.adultemployment.net displays correctly.

This is the virtual host configuration file for adultemployment.net:

```
<VirtualHost 100.0.193.102:80 192.168.14.202:80>
    ServerName AdultEmployment.net
    ServerAlias *.AdultEmployment.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@AdultEmployment.net
    DocumentRoot "/path.to/adultemploy/www"
    <Directory "/path.to/adultemploy/www">
        Options All MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /cgibin/badurl.pl
    ErrorLog "|/usr/local/sbin/rotatelogs /path.to/adultemploy/logs/error_log 86400"
    CustomLog "|/usr/local/sbin/rotatelogs /path.to/adultemploy/logs/access_log 86400" combined
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        ScriptAlias /cgibin/ "/path.to/adultemploy/cgibin/"
        <Directory "/path.to/adultemploy/cgibin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the virtual host configuration file for another site (which works correctly), bidsadult.com:

```
<VirtualHost 100.0.193.102:80 192.168.14.202:80>
    ServerName BidsAdult.com
    ServerAlias *.BidsAdult.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@BidsAdult.com
    DocumentRoot "/path.to/bidsadult/www"
    <Directory "/path.to/bidsadult/www">
        Options All MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /cgibin/badurl.pl
    ErrorLog "|/usr/local/sbin/rotatelogs /path.to/bidsadult/logs/error_log 86400"
    CustomLog "|/usr/local/sbin/rotatelogs /path.to/bidsadult/logs/access_log 86400" combined
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        ScriptAlias /cgibin/ "/path.to/bidsadult/cgibin/"
        <Directory "/path.to/bidsadult/cgibin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

The default and virtual host configurations are set in httpd.conf:

```
# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section provide defaults for any
#  <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#
ServerAdmin webmaster@occupant591.net
ServerName generic.occupant591
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.shtml index.htm index.html
</IfModule>
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
#
LogLevel info

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
    <IfModule ssl_module>
        LogFormat "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b" ssl_request
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-httpd-php         .php
    AddType application/x-tar               .tgz
    AddType text/plain                      .xml
    AddType image/x-icon                    .ico
    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

<Location /cgi-bin/phf*>
    Deny from all
    ErrorDocument 403 http://phf.apache.org/phf_abuse_log.cgi
</Location>
<Location /cgibin/phf*>
    Deny from all
    ErrorDocument 403 http://phf.apache.org/phf_abuse_log.cgi
</Location>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this file set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by any
# other <VirtualHost> definition.
#
Include /path.to.apache.config/conf/generic.site

# Virtual hosts
Include /path.to.apache.config/conf/ActiveSites/*.conf
```

The default site configuration is set by generic.site:

```
<VirtualHost 100.0.193.102:80 192.168.14.202:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@occupant591.net
    DocumentRoot "/path.to/generic/www"
    <Directory "/path.to/generic/www">
        Options All MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /cgibin/badurl-occ.pl
    ErrorLog "|/usr/local/sbin/rotatelogs /path.to/generic/logs-occ/error_log 86400"
    CustomLog "|/usr/local/sbin/rotatelogs /path.to/generic/logs-occ/access_log 86400" combined
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        ScriptAlias /cgibin/ "/path.to/generic/cgibin/"
        <Directory "/path.to/generic/cgibin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried to fix this by copying a functional configuration file onto the one for adultemployment.net and updating the domain name and directory entries.  That didn't change anything.  I've tried several different sets of ServerName and ServerAlias entries, such as

```
    ServerName www.AdultEmployment.net
    ServerAlias *.AdultEmployment.net AdultEmployment.net
```

and

```
    ServerName www.AdultEmployment.net
    ServerAlias *.AdultEmployment.net
```

I thought the problem might be because adultemployment.net was alphabetically first in the ActiveSites directory, so I added another domain to precede it - and that site works as expected, but adultemployment.net **still** doesn't return its page without a machine name.

At first I thought it might be a browser cache issue, but I get the same behavior accessing the site from Firefox and IE on my w2K machine, Firefox on my w7 laptop, and lynx ssh'd into an outside hosting company's shell.  I also tried clearing the arp entry for the domain on the server, to no avail.

I've tried tweaking the DNS entries, and looked for symlinks as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/94014/domain-without-the-www-gives-me-the-apache-it-works-page) or .htaccess entries as suggested [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache-hits-wrong-virtualhost-without-www-prefix-706981/) for similar problems, but nothing seems to fix this problem where ***one*** site on the server fails, but ***all*** of the others work correctly.

I've been trying to fix this problem for over a week, intermittently when I first discovered it, and almost continuously for the past two days.  Any hints or pointers would be **greatly** appreciated!!

Comment: ServerFault shows me this similar question http://serverfault.com/questions/94014/domain-without-the-www-gives-me-the-apache-it-works-page?lq=1 In short, try to switch which is the main host and the alias, and then even better don't serve the same content on both addresses with and without www but rather redirect from one to the other.

Comment: @Amiramix - If you look in my description, I tried switching the ServerName and ServerAlias settings, that didn't solve the problem.  Also, the link you cited is one of the ones I referenced as part of my research.

Comment: OK, but did you try to redirect one domain to the other? Is there any reason why you want to server the same content on both domains?

Comment: Redirection is a red herring: Serving the same content at one or more URLs has _nothing_ to do with making Apache serve the base domain correctly.  a) If I put everything on the base domain and try to redirect www to the base, _nothing_ will work because the assets don't exist in the generic site that Apache is serving instead.  Since the Apache isn't serving the base domain, there's no way to redirect it to www.
b) **All** of the other domains on the server work correctly _without_ redirection - why would I expect redirection to change the behavior of _this_ domain?

Comment: Apache is serving the base domain because it shows the default page. I was just wondering if adding a redirect from that domain would work. This would be just for debugging, to try a yet different configuration option. Also for debugging you could try to switch from Apache to Nginx. Did you try to use the same Apache configuration on a different server (if you have a backup or staging server for example)? You could also try disabling the www. subdomain temporarily or add another subdomain, .e.g "abc", to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Apache is showing the default page because the server is configured with a default page. The "base page" at adultemployment.net _should be_ the same contents as shown on www.adultemployment.net, but the generic (default) page for the server is displayed instead.  As I have stated, **the correct behavior occurs for all other domains on the server** e.g. bidsadult.com and erosmarkets.com show the same content with or without the www subdomain, not the generic site for undeveloped domains such as expertinaskirt.com, mature.bid or modelsinskirts.com as is served for the "base" adultemployment.com.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a "solution" (a work-around, actually, the fundamental cause is still unknown):

For *this* configuration (the second Apache configuration loaded at boot time), I had to add a `ServerName` entry duplicating the information in httpd.conf to the generic.site configuration file:

```
ServerName generic.occupant591
```

After adding the "default" `ServerName` entry, *all* of the sites served by *this* Apache configuration work correctly.  If a similar entry is added to the *other* configuration (the first one loaded at boot time), the sites matching the "default" `ServerName` entry fail.

**TL;DR;**

If a visitor attempted to access a non-existent page on an unconfigured domain (i.e., one *properly* being served through the generic.site configuration) such as *mature.bid/videos*, a `[core:info]` entry was written into the error log with the message `File does not exist: /web/generic-occ/www/videos` because the generic site doesn't have a file or directory named `videos` and so Apache has nothing to serve to answer the request.  While the error log entries illuminate the fact non-existent pages are being requested, they provide no *domain* information about the requests and are therefore really just noise.

I was using the stock Apache "combined" log format to generate the access logs.  Again, the access logs indicated the pages being accessed, but not the domain they were being requested from.  For normal configurations where the logs are recording information for a single domain, that's not a problem, but the generic.site configuration is designed to answer for *all* domains that are not otherwise configured, so logging the domain information is *required* in this instance to be useful.  Fortunately, Apache provides options for logging domain info, and `%v` for "*the canonical ServerName of the server serving the request*" seemed just what I needed. I created a new LogFormat statement:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %v \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" host_combined
```

I restarted Apache, tried to load *http://adultemployment.net* again, and found the access log contained an entry including `AdultEmployment.net "GET / HTTP/1.1"`  Great, I thought, that worked! - until I noticed the same text was logged when an unconfigured domain was accessed.  Perhaps I should be using `%V` for "*the server name according to the UseCanonicalName setting* to get the domain information?  I changed my LogFormat command to

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %V \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" host_combined
```

then restarted Apache - and found the domains with non-existent pages were being logged as I expected.  Now I have a record of which of the unconfigured sites are being accessed, and what pages visitors expect them to have.

This left me wondering why the LogFormat `%v` string logged "*AdultEmployment.net*" as "*the canonical ServerName of the server serving the request*" - ***none*** of the configuration files are written such that AdultEmployment.net should be the default server name.  (For the other Apache configuration on this machine, the `%v` string logged is "*Dreamer*" - the O/S machine name for the server.)  I can't find the page now, but during my earlier research I came across a situation where a similar problem was fixed by changing the domain name to not be the same as the operating system's server name.  I tried ssh'ing in to the IP address for this Apache configuration to see if AdultEmployment.net was showing up as part of the operating system configuration - but it wasn't, as I expected.

As an experiment I expected to cause problems, I tried adding a `ServerName` entry to the generic.site configuration file:

```
ServerName Dreamer.occupant591.net
```

I thought this might fix *adultemployment.net* (it did), but I expected it would also break *occupant591.net*, causing *it* to display the unconfigured site page.  However, it did *not* break the "host" site - in fact, I haven't been able to find anything failed now.

Since `apache2ctl -S` (as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/665965/apache-using-incorrect-default-virtual-host?rq=1)) isn't available with Apache 2.4 on FreeBSD, I read the `httpd` man page, and found `-S` is an option I can pass directly to the daemon.  With the `ServerName` entry in the generic.site configuration, the `httpd -S` report starts with

```
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.14.202:80      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server Dreamer.occupant591.net (/path.to.apache.config/conf/generic.site:6)
         port 80 namevhost Dreamer.occupant591.net (/path.to.apache.config/conf/generic.site:6)
         port 80 namevhost AAAAAAAAA-Dummy.com (/path.to.apache.config/conf/ActiveSites/AAAAAAAA-Dummy.conf:2)
                 wild alias *.AAAAAAAAA-Dummy.com
         port 80 namevhost AdultEmployment.net (/path.to.apache.config/conf/ActiveSites/AdultEmployment.net.conf:3)
                 wild alias *.AdultEmployment.net
```

When I remove the `ServerName` entry from the generic.site configuration, the `httpd -S` report starts with

```
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.14.202:80      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server AdultEmployment.net (/path.to.apache.config/conf/generic.site:6)
         port 80 namevhost AdultEmployment.net (/path.to.apache.config/conf/generic.site:6)
         port 80 namevhost AAAAAAAAA-Dummy.com (/path.to.apache.config/conf/ActiveSites/AAAAAAAA-Dummy.conf:2)
                 wild alias *.AAAAAAAAA-Dummy.com
         port 80 namevhost AdultEmployment.net (/path.to.apache.config/conf/ActiveSites/AdultEmployment.net.conf:3)
                 wild alias *.AdultEmployment.net
```

Note that without the `ServerName` entry, the default server is still supposedly being set at `generic.site:6` ***even though there is no ServerName entry in the file**, at line 6 or any other line in the file*.  Clearly *something is broken* but I don't have time to chase this ghost any more right now.

When I was initially setting up this Apache configuration with two instances on the server, I had a `ServerName` entry in the other instance's configuration that included the full domain name.  That caused the "host" site to break, and I fixed *that* problem by removing the top-level domain component from the `ServerName` entry in httpd.conf, and removing the `ServerName` entry altogether from the generic.site configuration file.  I made the same changes to this configuration, which seemed to work until approximately when I reconfigured my network to get rid of my ISP's router.  The next time I tried to access *adultemployment.net*, I found the problem described in my question.

Now I'm puzzled by why the two instances of Apache behave differently - but I'm going to have to put off that investigation for when I have nothing to do and a staff to do it with...